# swapping two number using pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to swap two integer using pointers...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b,*i,*j;
printf("Enter two integer:");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
i=&a;
j=&b;
a=*j;
b=*i;
printf("\n %d \t %d",a,b);
return 0;
}
```

The input is

> 12 45

The output is

> 45 45

After some trials, I found that If I assigned the `b=*i` first and then assigned `a=*j`, the first integer i.e `12` is repeating..

Why this happens ?
In my understanding of pointer, this is what I've done.
I've assigned the `*j` (i.e value of variable stored in address of `a`) to `b` and `*i`(i.e value of variable stored in address of `b`) to `a`..

Please explains what really happens in this program..

Comment: It is unclear whether you are looking for a C or C++ solution. Because several answers already gave C++ solutions, I wouldn't remove the C++ tag. Please next time be specific on C++ XOR C, don't mix those languages up.

Comment: He said "C" in title, that's quite definitive I'd say.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, this is what you want to do:

```
int temp = a; //temp <- 12
a = b;        //a <- 45
b = temp;     //b <- 12
```

Conceptually, this is what you're doing:

```
a = b; //a <- 45
b = a; //b <- 45
```

---

You can do this "elegantly" if you're using C++11:

```
std::tie(b, a) = std::make_tuple(a, b);
```

Comment: +1 I like the C++11 variation. Could use an explanation why `tie(b,a) = tie(a,b)` wouldn't work though. And possibly a demo like `tie(d,a,b,c) = make_tuple(a,b,c,d)` to to show how it's more versatile. (For bonus points, a comparison of generated assembly code to show that it compiles to the same instructions)

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens:

```
i=&a; //i points to a
j=&b; //j points to b
a=*j; //assign the value of b to a
b=*i; //assign the value of a, which has been assigned to the value of b in the previous step
```

This is a workaround:

```
int temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Comment: Thanks.. I don't know how I forgot this simple logic. :D

Comment: Please chose an answer which most suitably answers your question and accept it as correct, so that it is shown at the very top.

Answer (score 3):

Simples:

```
#include<iterator>
std::iter_swap(i,j);
```

Or indeed

```
#include<algorithm>
std::swap(a,b);
```

Or for purists

```
using std::swap;
swap(a,b); // allow for ADL of user-defined `swap` implementations
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a=*j;
b=*i;
```

`i` points address of `a` after first statement `a` value become `45` and next assigning `a` value to `b` so `b` also becomes `45`

```
      addressof `a` 
      ^
i-----|

      addressof 'b' 
      ^ 
j-----|
```

Now when you make change to 
`a` then value dereferenced by  `i`  also changes.

simply use a temporary variable

```
int temp;
temp=*i;
*i=*j;
*j=temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
i=&a; //i points to a
j=&b; //j points to b
a=*j; // this statement is equvivalent to a = b; (since *j and b both are same)
so a = 45;
now
b=*i; // this statement is equvivalent to b = a; (since *i and a both are same) 
but a value is changed to 45 in previous statement, so the same 45 is assigned to b variable also
```

You could use temp variable

Comment: Yeah.. I forgot this simple logic.. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This is because i points to a, so as soon as you assign something to a, original value stored in a is lost. You can either introduce third variable temp to store value between assignments (like in one of the answers posted), or do some trick like

```
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
```

to avoid using third variable.

**EDIT** 
This technique would work only for unsigned integer type.

Comment: integer overflow lurking

Comment: @sehe Wouldn't it still work despite of overflow - since it is circularly overflowing, so substructions would take care of overflow?

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy except *signed* integer overflow is undefined

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: C++ defines only unsigned overflow.

Comment: Overflowing does reliably wrap-around only for unsigned data types. For signeds, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm so happy I don't even need to explain :/